# XML Caching issue in FLex

Tags: apache-flex

```
private function loadGallery():void {
                theSend.url = "http://localhost/userMana/file.xml";
                theSend.send();
            }
```

I am calling this XML in Flex Tree and its works fine, but when after an update in XML it does not update back in my TREE unless i compile my flex builder again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do this by appending the time to the XML url:

```
var now:Date = new Date();
theSend.url = "http://localhost/userMana/file.xml?" + now.getTime();
theSend.send();
```

non-cached every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, you saved my hours of searching.

Answer (score 1):

You could try flushing your local cache after you update. Stopping and starting "World Wide Web Publishing Service" (which is what it's called under Vista; XP will have a different name) should do it.

Comment: The web service (IIS, Apache, whatever) running on your computer can cache pages. Stopping and starting the service that distributes those pages will flush the cache so you get a fresh copy. We use this method on our ArcGIS Server services when changing an MXD refreshing the service didn't work. (And, for the record, I like the way your accepted answer did it. Much cleaner and quicker. Too bad we can't use that for our service.)